# What is the Möbius Function for graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, mobius-function

About 4 minutes into [his video on chordal graphs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txaGsawljjA), Donald Knuth mentions a variant of the Möbius Function for graphs. I was curious what it meant outside the context of number theory?

Comment: Hi. do you see how your answers could help [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297268/what-is-the-m%C3%B6bius-analoge-for-iharas-zeta-function?lq=1)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Möbius function in number theory, though older, is actually a special case of a more general notion of Möbius function. If $\langle P,\preceq\rangle$ is a poset, a closed interval of $P$ is a set of the form

$$[a,b]=\{x\in P:a\preceq x\preceq b\}\;;$$

$P$ is locally finite if each of its closed intervals is finite. Let $\mathscr{I}$ be the set of non-empty closed intervals of $P$, and fix a commutative ring $R$ with unity, the ring of scalars; $\mathscr{I}$ and $R$ together give rise to an [*incidence algebra*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_algebra) $A$ whose elements are the functions $f:\mathscr{I}\to R$. For $f,g\in A$ and $r\in R$ the sum $f+g$ and scalar multiple $rf$ are defined pointwise in the obvious way; a product is defined by

$$(f\mathrel{*}g)\big([a,b]\big)=\sum_{a\preceq x\preceq b}f\big([a,x]\big)g\big([x,b]\big)\;.$$

$A$ has a multiplicative identity $\delta$:

$$\delta\big([a,b]\big)=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }a=b\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Finally, $A$ has a Möbius function $\mu$ that can be defined recursively as follows:

$$\mu\big([a,b]\big)=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }a=b\\
-\sum\limits_{a\preceq x\prec b}\mu\big([a,x]\big),&\text{if }a\prec b\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

If $P=\Bbb Z^+$ and $\preceq$ is $\mid$ (‘divides’), $\mu\big([m,n]\big)$ turns out to be the number-theoretic $\mu\left(\frac{n}m\right)$. You’ll find other examples at the link given above. [This PDF](http://www.mth.msu.edu/~sagan/Slides/mfp2.pdf) gives more details but is still quite elementary. Richard P. Stanley’s notes ‘An Introduction to Hyperplane Arrangements’, which can be found [here](http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/arrangements/arr.html), also introduce the general Möbius function as part of some very general machinery, one application of which is to chordal graphs (under the name *supersolvable graphs*).

Comment: Hi. I don't see how this helps [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297268/what-is-the-m%C3%B6bius-analoge-for-iharas-zeta-function?lq=1)...

Answer (score 3):

There is a Moebius function defined on any partially ordered set. The number theory one is the function associated to the set formed by the non-negative integers, partially ordered by divisibility. For details from this view point see, .e.g.,  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_algebra or http://www.sfu.ca/~mdevos/notes/comb_struct/mobius.pdf

I don't have time to go through Knuth's lecture, so I cannot be sure what partial order he is using.

Comment: Hi. I don't see how this helps [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297268/what-is-the-m%C3%B6bius-analoge-for-iharas-zeta-function?lq=1)...